# Which method is part of invoice class

Tags: class, uml, sequence, diagram, sequence-diagram

I’m learning UML and have the following diagram:

[image: click here]

I am confused between b or d answer. Can anyone explain which is the right one?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence diagram shows exchanges of messages performed between objects represented as lifelines. By the way, the diagram is formally incorrect, as the class name should be preceeded by a `:`, to show that it’s an object of that class.

The message, when it has the signature of a method correspond to a method of the receiving object. The object of class `Invoice` receives `Publish()` and `Validate()`, these would be expected to be methods. The dashed arrow corresponds to return message and not a distinct method.

(The question can in reality not be answered for sure, because in theory, messages could also correspond to signals, which may or may not be implemented as methods).

Comment: The colon is only to identify the type of the lifeline (see p. 570 of UML 2.5). Without it's just a name and still valid. See also p. 126: _An InstanceSpecification is depicted using similar notation to its classifiers, but in place of the Classifier name appears an underlined concatenation of the instance name (if any), a colon (‘:’) and the Classifier name or names._

Comment: @qwerty_so I agree that there is se flexibility about what a lifeline is. However, if it is supposed to represent a class, and at the same time underlines the name to suggest an instance as you rightly pointed out, there is solething incorect in the notataiin: either no reference to a class (but the redt of the question assumes it) or a correct rzference ;-)

Comment: You were an the bus again, heh ;-) Yes, I guess there is some (bad) history. With EA you still (!!) can use classes to represent lifelines. There's only some good hidden sentence that it will clobber your model. And, oh wonder, there are frequent questions why models got corrupt..